# Can I get Firefox to remind me to restart it if needed?

Tags: firefox

I have Firefox set to install updates automatically, and it does so, but it does so completely silently.
Which is fine for the most part, but for example today I've read about a critical vulnerability having been patched recently, and it would've been nice of Firefox to actively remind me that something important has been fixed and so I should restart it to apply the fix.

So I don't want to be bothered about every update, and I certainly don't want updates to stall because I didn't notice some reminder (or I canceled one because I was doing something important), but I'd appreciate periodic reminders to restart firefox if some important security update has been applied and I haven't restarted yet.

Is it possible to achieve something like this, natively or via an addon?

Comment: If you are not getting these messages then something is wrong. Maybe you should reinstall Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

normally Firefox will do this for you: if restart is required a different colored bar will appear below your address bar mentioning this.

Otherwise changes are applied on the fly or upon restart.